# Professors who use their own idiosyncratic names for things

Tags: language, lecturer

I sometimes have professors who use their own names for things. For example in lecture one kept referring to the "perfect marriage algorithm" but after talking with him I'm fairly certain he was referring to the [Stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). This is a challenge for me as I prefer to learn a little about a topic before going to a lecture, or read up on points discussed in the lecture after it. Are there any suggestions on how to approach this? The prof from the example above told us not to use Google to learn material for the class. With that said, he's a very reasonable and intelligent man, but I've been in other classes where profs have used nonstandard terminology (such as in math saying solve a problem by symmetry) and it would be difficult to talk to them.

I don't want to offend them by suggesting the name their using is wrong, but it makes studying from other resources hard and I don't think it's practical to try to learn everything just from lecture.

Comment: I know some cases where faculty make up their own names for things precisely so you can't just google the topic easily.  Often the point is to make you try to think for yourself, which is not a bad thing.

Comment: To paraphrase Feynman: when you learn the name of a thing, all you've learnt about is how people name things; you haven't learnt about the thing itself.

Comment: It is also possible that the same concept has different names. For example, the famous Squeeze Theorem in maths is also known as Pinching Theorem or Sandwich Theorem or Policemen Theorem. Especially if the teacher comes from a different culture, it may genuinely think its notations/terminology are standard. Using point 3 of grauwulf's answer helps to know if you are in this situation.

Comment: I would use Google anyway.  As long as you only use Google to learn concepts and don't use it to give you hints on the homework problems, I don't see how a professor can reasonably stop you from going online.  That would be like saying "I'm teaching you real analysis, but you're only allowed to listen to ME, you're not allowed to talk about real analysis with anyone else."  Which is super controlling in my opinion.  (For instance how would you know he's not feeding you wrong information, if you can't verify it with other sources?)  It's not fair to prevent students from getting second opinions

Comment: @Ben Bitdiddle: There are certain pedagogical approaches (such as the Moore method) that rely on the students developing standard material for themselves. In that sense, the  entire course is homework, and the approach is spoiled if the students Google anything.

Comment: "Google" is a red herring. The problem is that this prevents you from using *textbooks*! Suppose I want to see what different textbooks say about [compact operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operators). If my professor calls them "well-behaved operators", I will not be able to use *any* textbook, because they won't discuss "well-behaved operators". This is not "teaching students to learn for themselves". This is obfuscation, and sabotaging the entire academic enterprise. Learning is hard enough, there is *no excuse* for making it even harder by inventing your own terminology.

Comment: @Taladris - My undergraduate analysis teacher used to refer to the Squeeze Theorem as the Fly-Swatter Theorem, a bit more gory and violent, but it certainly gets the point across. Nowadays, I try to use standard terminology and mention some of the non-standard terms that are used.

Comment: There is a "stable marriage theorem" (aka Gale-Ryser theorem) and a "perfect marriage theorem" (aka Hall perfect-matching theorem), and the two are **not the same**. If your professor uses the name of one of them for the other, it is more of a mistake than an idiosyncrasy. That said, please make sure it isn't you who is doing the mixing-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tough one because it is a topic that meanders into psychology. I have encountered similar problems when professors insist on calling, that thing that everyone else calls agrees on as blue, pink. I will also add that I agree that this is an "academia" problem, as it relates to distribution and comprehension of information.

Three techniques for clarification that I have tried. YMMV.

1. Ask the professor why they feel the need to be an opaque and pedantic prat. Tell them to stop making up new names for things to feel better about their pathetic little existence and use the language of the field. This method has been met with some ... "resistance". :-P
2. Ask the professor is X has any adjacent concepts or theories that might be good to look up. This is dangerous as sometimes the prof. will decide to wax poetic on the art of Edvard Munch when you started out talking about impedance mismatch. Use with caution.
3. Ask the professor about the similarities and differences between X and Y. On a few occasions I have been VERY surprised to learn that I had completely misunderstood the point they were trying to make. All I needed to do was ask the simple question of "is this like such and such?" This has worked several times. BONUS: This approach has also led to some interesting discussions that worked back around to my area of research.

Jokes aside, the common theme here is 'to ask'. :-) As for "don't use google"... I don't know what to say about that. I guess you could ask for other reference material to gain a better understanding of the topic but google scholar is a pretty awesome/terrible research tool to use as a handicap. (IMHO)

Good luck with your class.

Comment: I'm really glad that (2) is a well-established pattern.

Comment: I agree with 2 and 3, but I doubt that 1 will be much help in this situation.

Answer (score 7):

Politely asking for a little clarification has worked well for me.  Is "term x" similar to "term y"?  Sometimes this is met with "Yes, term x is what I call term y."

For example, my Data Structures professor was using a term that I would deem "non-standard".  He was discussing "k-trees", but it was clear from the context that he didn't mean k-trees from graph theory.  I asked him if "k-trees" were similar to "k-ary trees".  That led to him explaining the similarities between what he calls "k-trees" and "k-ary trees".

Then again, not every professor is so helpful.